# Syntax for declaring a function returning a 2DArray in F#

Tags: multidimensional-array, syntax, f#, option-type

I need to declare a function in F# that takes 2 parameters (row, col) and return an 2-dimensional array of Option (intitializing all elements to be none), but I don't know the right syntax. I've tried something like:

```
type T = 
  {
   ....//my type
  }

let create2DArrayOfT (row : int , col: int) Array2D<Option<T>> = Array2D.init<Option<T>> 10 10 (fun -> None)
```

the signature above is wrong in specifing the return type.
So I have 2 questions:

1. What's the right signature for specifying the return type as a 2-dimensional array?
2. I've tought to use Option for the elements of my array because I want it to allow some locations to be empty. Is this reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify return type as that will be deduced by type inference.
Just use:

```
type T = {Name : string}
let create2DArrayOfT (row : int , col: int) = Array2D.init<Option<T>> 10 10 (fun _ _ -> None)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want specify return type use:

```
let create2DArrayOfT (row : int , col: int) : Option<T> [,] = Array2D.init<Option<T>> 10 10 (fun _ _ -> None)
```

Comment: ok thanks..I understand that I don't need to specify it, but what if I would like to? What should be the syntax? Since I have to put the returned array inside a mutable field of another type, I should know how to declare such field.

Answer (score 4):

The type of a 2D array is written `'a [,]` in F#. Next time, you can find this out using F# interactive by looking at the type of the functions in the `Array2D` module:

```
> Array2D.create;;
val it : (int -> int -> 'a -> 'a [,]) = <fun:clo@4>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let create2DArrayOfT<'T> (row : int , col: int) : 'T option [,] = Array2D.init<'T option> row col (fun _ _ -> None)
```

anotation omission

```
let create2DArrayOfT<'T> (row, col) = Array2D.init<'T option> row col (fun _ _ ->None)
```

usage:

```
let a = create2DArrayOfT<T>(2,3)
```